# Вывод gif анимации из php файла

Tags: gd, php

Есть архив с gif-анимациями. Хочу сделать учет всех загрузок анимаций (даже когда вставляют прямую ссылку на мои файлы на других сайтах). Для этого по совету на хешкоде в htaccess записал:

```
RewriteEngine on

\#if RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|GIF)

\#then RewriteRule ^.* gif.php [L]
```

Затем в файлу gif.php делаю запрос в БД на обновление информации о просмотрах запрошенной анимации, а после этого мне необходимо отдать саму анимацию (чтобы на всех сайтах, где сейчас висят хотлинки на мои анимации нормально отобразились изображения). Но как? Вот такой код:

```
header("Content-type: image/gif");

$img = imagecreatefromgif("./uploads/".$url);

imagegif($img);
```

Делает плохую гадость: функция imagecreatefromgif обрезает все кадры анимации, кроме первого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Content-Type: image/gif");
echo file_get_contents ("my.gif");
```